# Symfony 4 dump function doesn't work properly

Tags: php, symfony4

I'm developing some REST APIS and the dump function stopped working in my dev env, it doesn't show any information about anything or return the usual output

I tried to debug using the *dump()* function (from the */vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php* file) and the *\Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump()* function with the same results: it doesn't show anything or throw a php exception.

Also, i've tried both: use the regular debug commands (i.e *bin/console config:dump-reference*) and reinstall the debug-bundle

In this example my program returns a notification: *Array to string conversion*

```
$foo = array("asdads", "czxcxzc");
dump($foo);
```

In this other example the response is null

```
$foo = "bar";
dump($foo);
```

I just need the regular output for this function: is really useful to debug and see whats going on with my program

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? Can you add some code/examples ?

Comment: i've just added some code examples, and tried to be a lil more specific with the problem (srry, kinda noob)

Comment: are you in dev environment?

Comment: Yup, i am on my dev env

Comment: Do you have a `config/packages/debug.yaml` file? if so, please post it

Comment: @ArleighHix no, i dont have it... i've search in the whole git history for it with no luck

Comment: @GrecoJonathan how do i check that out?

Comment: `config/packages/dev/debug.yaml` ? or `.xml`, or `.php`?

Comment: @ArleighHix no, nothing at all...

Comment: @GrecoJonathan no, i dont have those. I believe that i have to update the post since im doing some REST Apis. That's a good thing to say i think xD

Comment: replace your dump function by dd(), is this working now ?

Comment: @GrecoJonathan it return this: Attempted to call function "dd" from namespace "App\Controller"

Comment: I've just discovered that since i've modified the App\Controller (for some thing that i need) class, this feature (and some other debug features) isn't available anymore. Im gonna take a deep look there in order to make this thing work again. 

Dumb question: should i close this post?

Comment: ANOTHER UPDATE

i've added the __destruct() method in the App\Controller class. if I remove it, everything works just fine, im gonna work over this

Answer (score 0):

I think that i've figure this out.

The problem was that i've added the `__destruct()` method on my main controller class (App\Controller)

App\Controller

```
abstract class Controller implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

use ContainerAwareTrait;
use ControllerTrait;    
...
public function __destruct()
{
   //Some stuffs here
}
```

I dont know why, but this method avoids loading for some of these debug methods (maybe some other features, but not sure about it)

The solution (for now) was moving this __destruct() method to my app main controller. Now everything works like a charm

Comment: I'm really curious what kind of stuff you had to put inside the `__destruct` method.

Comment: that's the weirdest thing: a monolog function!

Comment: That's so over engineered.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony var dumper , can change some object properties (when doing Caster stuff), so inside destruct function, your object could have a different type (such as array). You must check object type before calling object method or property, inside a destruct method.